# Cannot open include file: 'atlrx.h' in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2019, atl

We are upgrading the compiler from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2019.

Getting the below error while building the project which used regex expressions:
Cannot open include file: 'atlrx.h': No such file or directory

After installing the ATL/MFC Components also atlrx.h is not fond in the VS include directory.
Does anyone have any idea like which component should be installed to get rid of this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Googling "atlrx.h" shows quite a lot of information, you should be able to find something there.

Comment: You need to download ATL Server code, which is a separate on source library. The header is now there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download ATL server from Codeplex and install the files.
[ATL Server: Visual C++ shared source software](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/atl-server-visual-c-shared-source-software/)

And then copy the include file to a folder on your hard disk, Atlrx.h normally lives in the $(VCInstallDir)VC\atlmfc\include folder.

You should make sure that this path is added in the include directories of visual studio.